# Potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected after a call back from a payment gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm integrating a payment gateway to a web, and after having successfully paid, the gateway calls back my service with values abc... xmlns..

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult PDTHandler(FormCollection form)
    {        
        string NotifyMessage = Request.Form.Get("NotifyData");  >> error A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from <?xml....
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below setting in your web config file

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: here is the [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx) with MSDN reference for that

Comment: will that lead to any security hole ?  I guess I will only use it only for the plugin